# How do I handle the *response* when I get one back from an XMLHttpRequest "Post" operation?

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

I'm having a great deal of difficulty with this - I seem to be going in circles.
What I'm trying to do is POST data to a web service from a javascript on a client.

in the examples below, `valFname`, `valLname`, `valPhone`, and `valZip` all have valid string values:

```
function checkOffers(){
   // data collection from loaded form...


        var postData = "'FirstName':'" + valFname ;
        postData +="','LastName':'" + valLname ;
        postData +="','PhoneNumber':'" + valPhone ;
        postData += "','Zipcode':'" + valZip+"'";

        initialize(postData);
}



function initialize(postData) {
    //var postMsg = createSoapHeader(msg);
    var url = "https://server.company.com:9999/analytics/webservices/webservice.asmx/SamplePriorityOfferList";
    request.open("POST", url, false)
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState===4){
            //request is complete.  handle it
            processData;
        }
    };
    request.send(postData);
}

function processData(){
     response = request.responseXML.xml;
     alert("Returned Data:" + response);
}
```

I am calling the `checkOffers` function on the `PageLoad` event - I want the web service to fire without having to click a button, link, etc.

I'm getting nulls back from my request, but should be getting data. 
Any comments, tips, or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's impossible to say without seeing your server side code however I'd speculate that you intend to use response.responseXML (without the .xml)

Comment: Try `processData();` rather than just `processData;` (it helps to call your functions!) We'll also need to know what actual symptoms you're seeing, and what you're seeing when debugging the Javascript, at least the console output.

Comment: Is your script running on a page served from `https://server.company.com:9999`?

Comment: Do you know for sure that you're actually getting XML back?  Try putting in `alert("Returned Text: " + request.responseText);`.

Comment: @pete, no - that's just a generic value for where the webservice is running... but,  is the variable 'url' supposed to be that, or where the script is running?  The script is running on a server somewhere in the cloud.  

No idea where that is (or what the actual server name is - all I have is a proxy address)

Comment: @CLuelessonTuesdays: I ask because you may be running into cross-domain scripting issues. To refine my question, is the page that has the script served from the same domain as the XML webservice?

Comment: @pete - nope.  The paget that has the script is NOT in the same domain as the web service.  The webservice is in "company.com" domain, and the script is actually part of a cloud-based CRM application.

The more I study this, the more I'm focused on creating a proxy to beat the cross-domain thing (I know that's a non-starter).

Comment: It seems like I *may* be getting somewhere.  I'm still not getting back what I want, but I can get a response header now.  Still getting a status 500 on the response though...

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
        if(this.readyState===4){
```

should be:

```
        if(this.readyState==4){
```

That should at least get you seeing the alert.

Comment: Why, `readyState` isn't actually a number? (I'm asking; I always assumed it was a normal number, like `4`.) (Plus the issue is they're seeing `null`, not that they're not seeing *anything*.)

Comment: Err, it is.  I'm getting my languages/operators mixed up. :(   This answer is plain wrong.

Comment: LOL.  Thanks for the responsiveness, guys.  I am indeed seeing a null.  Just for giggles I added in some javascript that looks for a specific string at the beginning and ending of the response:

        var startTag = "<string xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">";
        var endTag = "</string>";
        var valueStart = 0;
        var valueEnd = 0;
        valueStart = xmlHttp.responseXML.xml.indexOf(startTag, valueEnd) + startTag.length;
        valueEnd = xmlHttp.responseXML.xml.indexOf(endTag, valueEnd + 1);

<continued>

Comment: and then set up alerts to show me the value of 'valueStart' and 'valueEnd' when the readyState==4, since (as I understand it, that's when everything is finished.

the alerts are telling me that the values are 35 (because I set that string manually)  amd -1, respectively... so the end tag just isn't there.  I know it *has to* be since its XML, so I'm assuming that the whole thing is coming up null?